# @MetaMask / detect-provider: handle Accounts Changed

Tags: ethereum, solidity, provider, account, metamask

I'm using @metamask/detect-provider, when I use the second account of my Metamask wallet, this second account is not considered in execution. This is the first account that is always taken in the execution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

accountsChanged event will be emitted whenever you change the account. So write a callback to handle it. I just set it in a state.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // you have to write code to detect provider. [@metamask/detect-provider][1]
    // if there is no accound set it null as default
    provider &&
      provider.on("accountsChanged", () => setAccount(accounts[0] ?? null));
  }, []);
```

or

```
useEffect(() => {
      
        window.ethereum &&
          window.ethereum.on("accountsChanged", () => setAccount(accounts[0] ?? null));
      }, []);
```